# Have to run package twice for SSIS to connect to database

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2008

I have SSIS packages in both Visual Studio 2008 and 2013. I have connection managers to SQL Server 2008 and 2014 databases where I may be connecting via Windows or SQL Server Auth. When I run them, it says "Error: Failed to acquire connection "server.databasename". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection." I then simply stop it and rerun it immediately and it works. It does this every time for more than one package and I've ran them dozens of times. How can I get it to work the first time?

Update- Sometimes I have had to open the connection manager, enter the password, and then re-execute the package. Or change it to Windows Authentication.

I've changed the ProtectionLevel around, currently set to EncryptSensitiveWithPassword. I've set Run64bitRuntime to False, set Persist Security Info to True (in the Properties of Connection Manager), and set DelayedValidation to True for the Connection Manager as well as the Execute SQL Task. I should also mention I'm connected to a VPN on a different domain than I'm normally on and running VS using "Run as different user"

Connection Manager properties:
[image]

Comment: If you install [BIDS Helper](https://bidshelper.codeplex.com) the Expression Highlighter may show you that your connection manager is getting values from somewhere else... I'm not sure why you need Delay Validation set to True.

Comment: About Delay Validation- just something I was trying.  Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it

Comment: I have it installed but can't see yet how it will help me. It does not put the colored triangles or flags on this specific connection manager like it did for some other connections.

Answer (score 0):

Please right click you project, bring out the property window, change the CreatorName to your name and change ProtectionLevel to EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey. Persist Security Info to False and set DelayedValidation to False. Rebuild the project.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have tried these things- I get errors when I change the CreatorName, saying "the computer must be trusted for delegation and the current user account must be configured to allow delegation" and given that I really would prefer it to work with EncryptSensitiveWithPassword, I didn't dive in to those errors much.